# trying to define controller with module in angular

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I don't know what's wrong here.  An explanation would be lovely. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/natecraft/xKtwP/13/

```
<body data-ng-app="channelApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="channelController">
    Hello! {{ name }}
  </div>
</body>

var mod = angular.module("channelApp", []);
mod.controller = ("channelController", function($scope) {
$scope.name = "nate"; 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues causing this unexpected behavior. First, the syntax for the controller should be like this:

```
var mod = angular.module("channelApp", []);
mod.controller("channelController", function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "nate"; 

});
```

Second, the fiddle is setup incorrectly and still won't render properly after making the above fix. I have fixed the fiddle configuration in [this forked version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLrZA/).

I also created the code [example in CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdDnr) for further reference.

Comment: So the problem in jsfiddle is due to the use of the body-element? I tried to get the jsFiddle running but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle link. Sorry, I had replaced the `<body>` with a `<section>` during my debugging, but that wasn't the fix. The fiddle configuration fix involved clearing the "body tag" box under Fiddle Options and selecting the AngularJS library under Frameworks.

Comment: nate -Are the link to the fiddle and CodePen examples in my answer working for you?

Comment: nate - you still need to remove the `<body ng-app>` from the "body tag" edit box under the Fiddle Options sections on the left.

Comment: Thanks Adam it works!  I'm new to fiddle too so definitely learned a lot here.

Comment: That's what SO is all about.

Comment: Adam could you delete the name in the fiddle options of the links you posted.  thanks again